# Number of functions in $g(g(x))=g(x)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> A function is defined as $g:\{1,2,3,4\}\rightarrow \{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $g(g(x))=g(x)\forall x\{1,2,3,4\}.$ Then number of such functions are

Try: from $g(g(x))=g(x)$ implies $g(x)=x$Identity function , only one function exists.$\bigg(g(1)=1,g(2)=2,g(3)=3\bigg)$

or $g(x)=y\rightarrow g^{-1}(y)=x$ and $g(y)=x\rightarrow g^{-}(x)=y$

We have $8$ such function . Like if $g(1)=1,$ Then dearrangement of remaining $3$ objects which is $2$
So we have total $9$ function. But answer is $10$

Could some help me to solve it, thanks

Comment: Why do you know $g^{-1}$ exists?

Comment: The wording of the question is odd. You never define $f$, so why mention it?

Comment: And you don't want a derangement of the remaining three.

Comment: No i have not learn group theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that $g$ is bijective but the problem does not specify that.  $g(x)=1$ is an example of a function that meets the requirement but is not bijective.  I would claim there are many more than $10$.  You need to choose a nonempty subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to be taken to themselves.  There are $15$ choices for that.  When the subset is not all of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ each element that is not mapped to itself can be mapped to any of the elements that are.  An example would be $g(1)=1,g(2)=2,g(3)=1,g(4)=2$.  Our answer is to take $i$ as the number if idempotent elements so $$\sum_{i=1}^4{4 \choose i}i^{(4-i)}=41$$
per [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(%20(4%20choose%20i)i%5E(4-i))%20from%201%20to%204&rawformassumption=%22i%22%20-%3E%20%22Variable%22)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Given $S\subseteq \{1,2,3,4\}$ there are $|S|^{4-|S|}$ such functions that fix all the elements of $S$ and no other elements.

This should give $$\binom{4}{1}1^3+\binom422^{2}+\binom433^{1}+\binom{4}44^0$$ which is way more than your given answer of $10,$ so I'm guessing you forgot part of the question?

Comment: please explain . There are $|S|^{4-|S|}$ such functions.

Comment: That's why it is a hint. @DurgeshTiwari But the answer I get is way more than your given answer of $10,$ so maybe you have forgotten part of the question?